# Adding data to struct inside a function but ouside the values are empty

Tags: c, struct

First of all im sorry if this a newby Question but im just starting to learn C.

I have this struct

```
struct item_s {
unsigned id;
char manufacturer [16];
char model [16];
unsigned rack;
unsigned position;
unsigned quantity;
};
#define MAX_NR_ITEMS 10000
struct item_s stock[MAX_NR_ITEMS];
```

The struct gets filled with items like this

```
    while ((stock_size < MAX_NR_ITEMS) && (len == 6))
{
    stock[stock_size].id = id;
    strcpy(stock[stock_size].manufacturer, manufacturer);
    strcpy(stock[stock_size].model, model);
    stock[stock_size].rack = rack;
    stock[stock_size].position = position;
    stock[stock_size].quantity = quantity;
    stock_size++;
    len = fscanf(fp, "%i %s %s %i %i %i", &id, manufacturer, model, &rack, &position, &quantity);
}
```

This works perfectly fine but now when im trying to add another item in a function like this

```
    stock_size++;
    stock[stock_size].id = id;
    strcpy(stock[stock_size].manufacturer, hersteller);
    strcpy(stock[stock_size].model, modell);
    stock[stock_size].rack = regal;
    stock[stock_size].position = fach;
    stock[stock_size].quantity = nr;
```

it works fine if i print the items inside the function but whenever i try to access the new items outside of this function it just gives me empty values

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to properly add another item?

This is the code with some stuff cut that has no impact for this

```
//
//  stock.c
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* structure to store all information about items */

struct item_s {
    unsigned id;
    char manufacturer [16];
    char model [16];
    unsigned rack;
    unsigned position;
    unsigned quantity;
};


#define MAX_NR_ITEMS 10000
struct item_s stock[MAX_NR_ITEMS];
unsigned stock_size = 0;
unsigned structsize;

/* read at most max_nr items from file "filename" and write them to array items
 * the number of items actually read is returned */

void read_items_from_file(char *filename)
{
    // storage to preliminarily store the information of an item
    unsigned id; char manufacturer[16]; char model[16];
    unsigned rack; unsigned position; unsigned quantity;
    // number of tokens read from current input line
    size_t len = 0;

    // open the input file for reading
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        // if file could not be opened (wrong path, not readable, ...)
        // output a short message and immediately exit
        char resp;
        printf("Eingabedatei kann nicht geoeffnet werden.\n");
        scanf("%c", &resp);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // the following loop reads a new item in every iteration
    // until the end of the file (or an invalid entry appears)
    len = fscanf(fp, "%i %s %s %i %i %i", &id, manufacturer, model, &rack, &position, &quantity);

    // as long as there is space in the array and a correct line is read
    while ((stock_size < MAX_NR_ITEMS) && (len == 6))
    {
        stock[stock_size].id = id;
        strcpy(stock[stock_size].manufacturer, manufacturer);
        strcpy(stock[stock_size].model, model);
        stock[stock_size].rack = rack;
        stock[stock_size].position = position;
        stock[stock_size].quantity = quantity;
        stock_size++;
        // reading next item
        len = fscanf(fp, "%i %s %s %i %i %i", &id, manufacturer, model, &rack, &position, &quantity);
    }

    // finally close the input file
    fclose(fp);
}

struct item_s enter_new_item(unsigned id){
    char hersteller [16];
    char modell [16];
    unsigned regal;
    unsigned fach;
    printf("\n Neue ID! Bitte geben sie den Hersteller an\n");
    scanf("%s", hersteller);
    printf("\n Bitte geben sie das Modell an\n");
    scanf("%s", modell);
    unsigned exitloop = 1;
    do
    {
        printf("\n Bitte geben sie das Lagerregal an\n");
        scanf("%i", &regal);
        printf("\n Bitte geben sie das Lagerfach an\n");
        scanf("%i", &fach);
        for(unsigned i=0; i<stock_size; i++)
        {
            if (regal == stock[i].rack && fach == stock[i].position){
                printf("\nDer ausgewählte Lagerort ist bereits belegt!");
                exitloop = 0;
            }
        }
    } while(exitloop == 0);

    printf("\nGeben sie die Anzahl der neuen Elemente ein\n");
    unsigned amount;
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    struct item_s new_item;
    new_item.id = id;
    strcpy(new_item.manufacturer, hersteller);
    strcpy(new_item.model, modell);
    new_item.rack = regal;
    new_item.position = fach;
    new_item.quantity = amount;

    return new_item;
}
void add_items_to_stock(unsigned id)
{
    unsigned newitem = 1;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<stock_size; i++)
    {
        if (id == stock[i].id){
            printf("\nID %d erkannt! Die neuen Artikel werden am gleichen Ort eingelagert (Regal %i Fach %i)", id, stock[i].rack,stock[i].position);
            printf("\nGeben sie die Anzahl der neuen Elemente ein\n");
            unsigned amount;
            scanf("%d", &amount);
            stock[i].quantity = stock[i].quantity + amount;
            newitem = 0;
        }
    }
    if (newitem == 1){
        structsize++;
        stock[structsize] = enter_new_item(id);
        printf("ID %d ", stock[structsize].id);
        printf("manu %s ", stock[structsize].manufacturer);
        printf("model %s ", stock[structsize].model);
        printf("rack %d ", stock[structsize].rack);
        printf("position %d ", stock[structsize].position);
        printf("quantity %d ", stock[structsize].quantity);
    }
}



void print_stock()
{
    for(unsigned i=0; i<structsize; i++) {
        printf("\n ID : %04d Hersteller : %s Modell : %s - Regal :  %d Fach : %d - Anzahl : %d\n",
               stock[i].id,
               stock[i].manufacturer,
               stock[i].model,
               stock[i].rack,
               stock[i].position,
               stock[i].quantity );
    }
}

int main()
{

    // read intial stock from files
    read_items_from_file("lager.txt");
    structsize = stock_size;
    //
    do {
        printf("\n\nSelect one\n");
        printf("(1) \n");
        printf("(2) Add Elements\n");
        printf("(3) \n");
        printf("(4) Print Inventory\n");
        printf("(0) End Programm\n");
        printf("\tYour Choice");

        unsigned  choice;
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        unsigned id;
        // menu items
        switch(choice)
        {

            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nGeben sie die ID des Elementes ein\n");
                scanf("%d", &id);
                add_items_to_stock(id);
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:
                print_stock();
                break;
            case 0:
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Incorrect Input\n");
        }

    } while(1);
}
```

The file where it gets its data looks like this

```
11 Hersteller-A Modell-A 54 4 12
22 Hersteller-B Modell-B 6 34 101
53 Hersteller-C Modell-C 14 20 20
84 Hersteller-D Modell-D 85 2 18
101 Hersteller-E Modell-E 25 4 12
102 Hersteller-F Modell-X1 56 3 101
322 Hersteller-F Modell-X2 61 70 20
411 Hersteller-G Modell-Y1 88 82 18
561 Hersteller-G Modell-Y2 95 4 12
772 Hersteller-G Modell-Y3 56 03 101
883 Hersteller-H Modell-H2 41 90 20
954 Hersteller-I Modell-I 68 92 18
```

Comment: You need to do the `fscanf` **before** you use the results of that to fill in `stock`. If that is not it then please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is very difficult to spot problems in code we can't see.

Comment: Post the complete code! How is the function defined? How do you call it? How do you print it ? How do yuo read in values in the function

Comment: I edited the question to include the code

Comment: @Freddy789 I found your bug. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this (emphasis added with comments):

```c
    while ((stock_size < MAX_NR_ITEMS) && (len == 6))
    {
        stock[stock_size].id = id;
        strcpy(stock[stock_size].manufacturer, manufacturer);
        strcpy(stock[stock_size].model, model);
        stock[stock_size].rack = rack;
        stock[stock_size].position = position;
        stock[stock_size].quantity = quantity;

        stock_size++;   //<<------------------ THIS LINE

        // reading next item
        len = fscanf(fp, "%i %s %s %i %i %i", &id, manufacturer, model, &rack, &position, &quantity);
    }
```

But in a later section you have this (emphasis added):

```c
    if (newitem == 1){

        structsize++;   //<<------------------  THIS LINE

        stock[structsize] = enter_new_item(id);
        printf("ID %d ", stock[structsize].id);
        printf("manu %s ", stock[structsize].manufacturer);
        printf("model %s ", stock[structsize].model);
        printf("rack %d ", stock[structsize].rack);
        printf("position %d ", stock[structsize].position);
        printf("quantity %d ", stock[structsize].quantity);
    }
```

Why do I point this out? Because you are keeping track of the number of items in your array by using `stock_size` which is incremented **after** the data is put into the array, but in the second block of code, you refer to the `structsize` which is initialized to equal `stock_size` but is incremented **before** the data is put into the array. This would result in the data looking like this in memory:

```
d = data
n = null

Initialize stock_size to 0.
Add first item and increment stock_size to 1.
---------
| 0 | 1 |
---------
| D | N |
---------

Add 2nd item and increment stock_size to 2.
-------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
-------------
| D | D | N |
-------------

Keep adding items and incrementing stock_size after adding the data until you've added 6 items.
-----------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-----------------------------
| D | D | D | D | D | D | N |
-----------------------------

Set structsize equal to stock_size.
Increment structsize to 7 and add item.
---------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
---------------------------------
| D | D | D | D | D | D | N | D |
---------------------------------
```

In my example, memory location represented by `stock[6]` is blank because you incremented  the index of the array at the wrong time and there is an uninitialized section of your array between good data. Switching it around and incrementing `structsize` after adding the data fixes this and the data will display properly.

See my code here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkLZ_7-lU